# Zend 2 How to Disable shared instantiation of services on the fly

Tags: caching, zend-framework2, service-locator

In Zend 2, we use the function get() to get the same instance of a service when we request it multiple times. It is created the first time and cached during the request. That's what a shared service is.

```
  $ar = $this->serviceLocator->get('ActionResponsibility');
```

Now a non-shared service will create a new instance every time it is requested. to do this we have to change the configuration file as following:

```
<?php
return [
'service_manager' => [
    'invokables' => [
        'MyService' => 'Application\Service\MyService',
        'AnotherService' => 'Application\Service\AnotherService',
    ],
    'shared' => [
        'MyService' => false,
        'AnotherService' => false,
        'ThirdPartyService' => true,
    ],

    // [...]
 ]
];
```

The Questions is, how can we get a new instance only when required in the code, isn't there a way in using the get() function to force a new instance instead of a cached copy?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `build` method instead of `get` to retrieve a new non cached instance.

```
$ar = $this->serviceLocator->build('ActionResponsibility');
```

Comment: Thank you, but the function build is supposed to be implemented in which class? I got this error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::build()

Comment: Which version of the servicemanager are you using? Ik think it has been added in V3 and higher, but I'm not sure. The `build` method has been added in https://github.com/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/commit/54d553ecd9d45648ea7f3b001e89d1c47a8179bb#diff-14ccad9c10b086d30c53ca4b694cae5d=

Comment: Alternatively you can try setting the service to non shared using `setShared` method, before retrieving the service. After retrieving reset it to the old value.